# Parts of Mesh are missing when importing .blend object to unity

Tags: modeling, import, unity

I've made a 3d object and tried importing it into unity for use. It seems just fine in blender but after import this happens:

[image: missing mesh parts in unity]
This is what it looks like in blender

[image: the same 3D object in blender]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Been stuck on this for a while. Tried converting to .fbx and other formats and importing too but in vain.

Comment: Try recalculating your normals?

Comment: @RonJensen I tried recalculating the normals (using recalculate normals outside). Did not seem to work. Also I had dissolved a few vertices while trying to create the 3d object above- not sure if it might have made a mess.

Comment: I'm not up on Unity, but I've seen things like this when moving meshes from 2 sided engines to single sided engines, some normals are reversed so faces "disappear". Looked like there might be shading issues in that area, too.

Comment: Oh. Do you have any tips on how to troubleshoot this?